# Musclesoft jquery-connections plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to ask, if it's possible to connect some html elements in pairs.
https://github.com/musclesoft/jquery-connections

Now i have this html code:

```
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="description"></div>

<div class="point"></div>
<div class="description"></div>

<div class="point"></div>
<div class="description"></div>
```

and some js code:

```
$().connections({
        from:'.point',
        to: '.description',
    });
```

Now the problem is, that every point is connected to every description. I want to have elements joined in pairs, so every point is connected to only closest description.

Thanks for help.

Comment: i have wrapped every point and description div inside parent div (.test), and use:$('.test').connections({
            from:'.point',
            to: '.descs',
        });
but all points are connected...

Answer (score 0):

I created loop:

```
$('.point').each(function( index ) {
    $('.point').eq(index).connections({ to: $('.description').eq(index)});
});
```